# Send captured image to another UIViewController with prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I'm trying to send the captured image to another `UIViewController`.

So when I press captured button, it's taking a photo and I can save the image in my camera roll. But when I want to see image in another view I can't see it.

This is my code :

```
- (IBAction)captureButton:(id)sender
{
    [self.cameraViewController captureImageWithCompletionHander:^(id data) {
        self.image = ([data isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) ? [UIImage imageWithData:data] : data;
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.image, nil, nil, nil);
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"savingSegue" sender:self];
    }];
}
```

And this is the prepare for segue method.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"savingSegue"]) {
        PhotoSaveViewController *pvc = [[PhotoSaveViewController alloc] init];
        [pvc.imageView setImage:self.image];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your second view is a `PhotoSaveViewController` then replace your `prepareForSeque` method with this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"savingSegue"]) {
        PhotoSaveViewController *pvc = (PhotoSaveViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        if (pvc)
            [pvc.imageView setImage:self.image];
    }
}
```

Indeed, it's not your job to instantiate the destination `UIViewController`, your `UINavigationController` have already done that.

Comment: When I use it its saying unrecognized selector sent to instance.So app is crashing.

Comment: Use debugger to inspect the object you got with `segue.destinatonViewController`. It might not be your ViewController if it's embed on a `UINavigationController` or a `UITabBarController`. In this case, you will have to follow the links to got it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `imageView` on `PhotoSaveViewController` it is outlet and it is not set at this moment. You should declare there some other property like

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *inputImage;
```

and assign to that in `prepareForSegue`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"savingSegue"]) {
        PhotoSaveViewController *pvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        pvc.inputImage = self.image;
    }
}
```

Then do the following in the `PhotoSaveViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imageView.image = self.inputImage;
}
```

Another approach you can create it from code totally. Assign `Storyboard ID` to the `PhotoSaveViewController` and then do the following:

```
- (IBAction)captureButton:(id)sender {
    [self.cameraViewController captureImageWithCompletionHander:^(id data) {
        self.image = ([data isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) ? [UIImage imageWithData:data] : data;
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.image, nil, nil, nil);
        PhotoSaveViewController *dvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhotoSaveViewControllerID"];
        dvc.inputImage = self.image;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Actually first I did like this. But I couldn't see image again.

Comment: So maybe your outlet not connected at all?

Comment: Please look at the updated answer. I didn't notice another issue with `PhotoSaveViewController` in your code. Now I fixed it too

Comment: application is crashing now.
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d631270'

Comment: Look at your storyboard, you have connected to `savingSegue` another `UINavigationController` not the `PhotoSaveViewController`

Comment: Please refer that [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ5iF.png) to see how it should looks like